# Hide Url in PopUp

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to hide url in the popup window opened using window.open

var strWindowFeatures = "menubar=no,location=no,url=hide,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,status=yes";
    window.open("BAMBranchSearch.jsp?&honame="+a,"8",
    "width=700,height=450,left=0,top=150,menubar=no,url=hide,status=yes,location=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=no");

Comment: You can use an iframe

Comment: i don't know how to add i frame